# elif condition in django view

Tags: django, if-statement, view

I'm having view function which filters object according to the data I give and if that filtered object does not exist in the database it adds the object to DB(i didn't write add function yet). Shows error if it exists already. I'm getting data from a template using ajax post request.

```
#view.py
@csrf_exempt
def setUserInDB(request):
if request.method=="POST":
    if request.POST.get('pname','u_id'):
        pname = request.POST.get('pname')
        u_id = request.POST.get('u_id')
        user = userprofile.objects.get(pk=u_id)
        pid = Project.objects.get(title=pname)
    else:
        u_id = None
        pname = None

    if request.POST.get('db_id','chkbox'):
        db_id = request.POST.get('db_id')
        db = Db_profile.objects.get(pk=db_id)
        chkbox = request.POST.get('chkbox')
        print chkbox
    else:
        db_id = None
        chkbox = None

if Projectwiseusersetup.objects.filter(userid=user,project_id=pid, 
db_profileid=   db,setasdefaultproject=chkbox): 
    print "already exist"

elif (((Projectwiseusersetup.objects.filter(userid = user,project_id = 
pid,db_profileid=db,setasdefaultproject=False)).exists()) and 
(chkbox==True)):
    print "FtoT"


elif Projectwiseusersetup.objects.filter(userid = user,project_id = 
pid,db_profileid=db,setasdefaultproject=True) and chkbox==False:
    print "TtoF"
else:
    print "aaaa"
```

user,pid,db,chkbox   }---- i'm getting these data from ajax post request,
userid, project_id, db_profileid, setasdefaultproject(boolean) }----- model fields

when I try to check my elif condition, i'm getting output in console "aaaa"(else part). what is wrong with elif?

Comment: Still not clear! Please clearly mention what you wanted to achieve? You are getting the ajax request and based on that you have create a filter and `print "FtoT" ` ?

Comment: Please explain the problem *clearly* and post the full view.

Comment: my elif function is correct or not? @Raja Simon

Comment: you can check my exc. it is a simple version (i don't check your conditions)

Answer (score 0):

Here the ex:

```
x = 4

if x == 1:
    print ("1")
elif (x == 2):
    print("2")
elif (x == 3):
    print("3")
else:
    print("4")
```

Comment: request.POST.get('pname','u_id')

you should replace it with:

'pname' in request.POST and 'u_id' in request.POST

Comment: and 1 more thing:
You set the conditions don't clear, you should make it better